# angularjs and highcharts, labels not shown unless I hover over the data points

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm using angularjs with highcharts, and I'd like to show the all the labels without hover on the data points, like in here:

[image]

According to the documents, the following chart options should work

```
plotOptions: {
  line: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    enableMouseTracking: false
  }
},
```

But with ng-highcharts, I'm only getting this,

[image]

Any ideas why?

Attached source code

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="main" style="margin-top: 60px; ">
  <highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig">
  </highchart>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['highcharts-ng']);
app.controller('main', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.chartConfig = {
    chart: {
      type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Test'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Price'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      line: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        },
        enableMouseTracking: false
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Field1',
      data: [100, 105, 108, 111, 130]
    }, {
      name: 'Field2',
      data: [210, 215, 218, 231, 240]
    }]
  };
}]);
```

Comment: This seems to work for me: http://codepen.io/DeividasK/pen/NpKZjN?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me. Maybe your `$scope.chartConfig` is modified somewhere else?

Working example: http://codepen.io/DeividasK/pen/NpKZjN?editors=1010

Comment: It works with angularjs 1.6, while I'm using a 1.4 version installed long time ago with bower. It has nothing to do with highcharts